# How to cgo link to libraries built with LLVM's libc++

Tags: go, llvm, clang++, cgo, libc++

I would like to CGO link my go program to a c++ static library linked to [LLVM's libc++](https://libcxx.llvm.org/). With GNU's libstdc++, everything works fine.

I am calling go compiler as follows:

```
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++ -I/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include" CGO_LDFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++ -L/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lpthread -lrt -lc++ -lm -lc" go test --ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' -c -a .
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing [`-lc++ -lc++abi`](https://releases.llvm.org/11.0.0/projects/libcxx/docs/UsingLibcxx.html#using-libc-on-linux).